# Does $\mathbb{N} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I thought that ($\mathcal{P}$ is the powerset) $$\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathcal{P}(\{0, 1, 2, ..., n\}) = \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mathcal{P}(\{0, 1, 2, ..., n\})$$

But recently found out this is wrong.

So I wonder, does $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\} =^{?} \bigcup_{n = 1}^{\infty} \{0, 1, 2, ..., n\} =^{?} \mathbb{N}$$

And if *yes*, how come the first equation does not hold?

Comment: What is the definition of $\lim_n \{0,1,2,..,n\}$?

Comment: $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{1,...,n\}=\mathbb{N}$ for sure and $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{P}(\{1,...,n\})\subset \mathcal{P}$ but it contains only finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ and not $2\mathbb{N}$ for example.

Comment: One does indeed have that $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\{0,\dots,n\}$, but the analogous equation for powersets fails because every set $X$ that is in $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\mathcal{P}(\{0,\dots,n\})$ belongs to some $\mathcal{P}(\{0,\dots,n\})$, hence is a subsets of said $\{0,\dots,n\}$ and is **finite**. But there are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, such as $\mathbb{N}$ itself, that are **infinite**.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is.

If $A_n:=\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ then evidently: $$\limsup A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=\{0,1,2,\dots\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k=\liminf A_n$$ so that $\lim A_n$ is defined and takes value $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$.

---

edit concerning comparing with $\wp(A_n)$

If $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq\cdots$ and $f$ operates on sets on a monotonic way (i.e. $A\subseteq B\implies f(A)\subseteq f(B)$) then we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$ and of course also $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(A_n)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f(A_n)$.

But we **cannot** just state that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}f(A_n)=f(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)$.

So it does not have to be true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(A_n)=f(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n)$

Comment: What is the definition of lim sup for a sequence of sets? I only know the definition for the sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 I made my answer more complete with an edit. An element $x$ belongs to the limsup if $x\in A_n$ is true i.o. It belongs to the liminf if $x\in A_n$ almost always (so not for at most a finite times).

Comment: Thanks. But this is not a correct definition. It has to be $\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}$. So as here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes_superior_und_Limes_inferior_von_Mengenfolgen

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 Indeed. A typo. Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: The OP had another question about the first equation. See my and Olivier Begassat´s comment. Could You include this in Your answer?

Comment: @PeterMelech I will have a look at it.

Comment: @PeterMelech I have edited.

Comment: @drhab Thank You. Very well! I upvoted.